# How to execute python script in android application with Embed python interpreter ?

Tags: android, python

I need to create a app for to execute python script. This is basically a learnning application for python beginners. Student can write python code and then they run the python file it should show the result. Basically this app provide python lessons for students, according to the lesson i need to provide testing environment for them. So how can i do this ?

Comment: Actually i'm still finding way for embed the python interpriter? I need to know how to embed the python interpriter on android app.

Comment: It sounds like you still have some research to do. Start by Googling for running shell commands, then finding a python interpreter. Besides, there are plenty of apps out there that do this already.

Comment: this concept is really easy for BusyBox since linux (ie: `bash` scripts are relatively native to android's OS) as for a direct python interpreter, not quite sure. Did a brief query awhile back and didn't end up finding anything. Perhaps there is a way to compile BusyBox to include Python. Since Python isn't native to Android but it is for Linux.

Comment: yh this is already exist. But this app is diffrent than them. Thanks for your recomandation @JaredBurrows. its help me lot.

Comment: @BiTinerary that is good point for me. For the shell commands, is that phone need to rooted ?

Comment: Do you have a python interpreter library? My idea will be to have binaries for interpreter, load them using System.loadLibrary, run command line or saved in a file script using Runtime.exec().

Comment: @JohnnyDoe No. Do you have library ?